# I am able to record the HTTPS requests using Jmeter, But getting error while inputing the data

Tags: json, jmeter

I am able to record the `HTTPS` requests using `Jmeter` proxy settings, by enabling the "Use this Proxy for all protocols" (path: option --> Settings --> Advance Settings --> Network)

I m facing the issue whenever i m imputing some value after logging into the application. For eg: after login to the application, there is search field where in I provide some parameter and click on search, system is throwing the error as

> Error[object object]

Unable to proceed with the recording. Please help. If i check the request response through the firebug, only the request is passing and there is no response for that request

Provided the URL and the `Json`.

```
{"query":{"simple":{"filter":[{"key":"serviceNumber","value":"97970844"},  
{"key":"isNotDealerUser","value":true}]}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you accept the certicate emited by JMeter ?

To do that, use Firefox, call in browser the URL, accept security exception.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder

Comment: hello, are you sure the comment is for me ? I answer question here. I am not asking

Comment: This link is from JMeter reference. If it disappears then it means JMeter has been retired for years. As Apache guarantees that documentation is kept even for retired software.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, you’ll need to test URLs, which can sometimes be restricted from anonymous visits. The types and resources can vary from corporate libraries and  knowledge bases to targeted forums or others. All tend to have limited or restricted access.

For instance, if you download something from a FTP server, you would encounter the "gatekeeper" screen shown below. This pop-up window is generated by a browser when the server requires a username/password. The frame will vary from browser to browser (e.g. Mozilla Firefox, Apple Safari, or Microsoft Internet Explorer), but regardless, a username/password is required to access what are often some basic resources.
 BlazeMeter: HTTP Basic Authentication

That’s where the term "HTTP Basic Authorization" comes from. And you must have a strategy to handle this when you’re working with JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

When you record JMeter what is the sampler setting you are using. In most cases in case of HTTPS you might want to try using Java. By default JMeter picks HttpClient4. Try changing the HttpClient3 or Java and it should resolve your issue.